# How to write out all directory names into a text file

Tags: bash

I want to make a list of my subdirectories. When I execute the following for loop, the first directory name occurs two times

```
for d in */; do
     echo $d >> directories.txt
done
```

The output is like :

```
ONE/
TWO/
ONE/
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Improving you current code, this command should be helpful:

```
for d in ./*;do [[ -d "$d" ]] && echo "$d" >> dir.txt; done
```

To remove the `./` from the output:

```
for d in ./*;do [[ -d "$d" ]] && echo "${d##./}" >> dir.txt; done
```

Comment: the sed wasn't working for me, so I updated it with this `sed -r 's/^\.\///'`

Comment: You right I missed a `/` at the end! Thanks for the HUD.

Comment: @muru I tried this `for d in ./*;do [[ -d "$d" ]] && echo "${d%/}";done` and it didn't give the output you suggest, this rather `"${d##./}"` does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You are appending the entries `(>>)` where you must be overwriting them `(>)`. It is better to use `find`. To find all subdirectories recursively, use

```
find . -type d > directories.txt
```

To find subdirectories only in the current directory, use

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 > directories.txt
```

`-type d` instructs find to list only directory files.

Answer (score 1):

What surprises me is the lack of a semicolon (;) in your solution, does your problem persist when you do:

```
for d in *; do echo $d >> directories.txt; done
```

? It works for me fine. Also, are you sure you run it in bash? Finally, the ">>" might be the problem, you might be appending directories' names several times.

Not to mention that if you want to list directories only (not files) you could rather do:

```
for d in `find . -type d -maxdepth 1`; do echo $d >> directories.txt; done
```

or even simpler:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 > directories.txt
```

Comment: I see 'maxdepth 1' in the other answer that just appeared. Indeed, I omitted it, adding now for consistency.