# ls < text.txt (with files in subdir and resolution of files)

Tags: display-resolution, ls, media

Long time lurker, first time questioneer!

I can't find the following: I would like to make a textfile which is filled with filenames including the ones in subdir's, their path and and metadata (especially video resolution). All that from console.

I couldn`t find something similar, only something called mediainfo which gets close, but only works for 1 file as far as I see.

Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks for your time! Cheers

And please keep your hands of my question.

Comment: What do you mean with 'resolution'? Size in bytes?

Comment: By resolution i mean the size of the mediafile. F.e. with a video it could say 600x480

Comment: Almost duplicate https://askubuntu.com/q/994602/295286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the way one takes a 1-argument command (`mediainfo foo`) and applies it to a bunch of files, is with `find` and `xargs`. See `man find;man xargs`.

I'm using the NUL-terminated options (`-print0` and `-0`) because you did not say no filename had spaces.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 mediainfo
```

Comment: Not sure on double negative not and no. But I would assume most people have spaces in their filenames.

Comment: It works with filenames, even the ones with spaces in it, and its writing correctly to a text file with "<". Got alot of "extra information" but its going in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Or use `-exec mediainfo {} \;` There's no point in passing to `xargs`. And yes `-exec` will handle filenames with spaces

Answer (score 1):

`mediainfo` is an excellent choice for obtaining this information. I would use a script to ensure I was getting the results I wanted on a single file and then iterate it across the scope desired. Here's an example I called `1linenfo.sh` and placed in my `~/bin` directory:

As with all scripts you plan on executing you'll have to change the permissions to executable. in this specific case that would be `chmod +x ~/bin/1linenfo.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash
pfx=$(mediainfo --Inform="General;%CompleteName%" "$1")
sfx=$(mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%x%Height%" "$1")
Title="$pfx $sfx" #build desired line of output
echo "$Title" #output
```

The above includes the information that you want but you can easily add more. For more detailed output choices check the output of `mediainfo --Info-Parameters`

You can easily utilize find to iterate this across your desired scope.

`find . -type f -exec bash -c '1linenfo.sh "{}"' \;`

If you need to redirect the output to a file you can do something like this:

`find . -type f -exec bash -c '1linenfo.sh "{}"' \;>report.txt`

If anything about this answer is unclear, drop me a comment and I'll do me best to clarify.

Comment: If the script is in `~/bin` and OP already sourced `~/.bashrc` then there's no need for `bash -c` part, the `-exec` flag will search directories in `PATH` and find the script just fine. And of course it needs executable permission, so may wanna mention `chmod +x` on the script